# How to remove and animate element in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The story is this: just learning react, doing a to-do-list app, have the following structure of my app:

- function Task
- class Tasks
- class ToDoList

Function Task:

```
function Task(props){
    const [close, setClose] = useState(false);
    const [task, setTask] = useState(props.toDo);

    let animation = "task";
    console.log("[TASK] ", task)
    if (close){
        setTimeout(() => {props.onRemoveClick()}, 500);
    }
    close ? animation += " remove_task" : animation += " add_task";


    return(
        <div className={animation} key={props.id}>
           <input 
              className="task_text" 
              value={task} 
           />
           <div className="delete_task" onClick={() => {setClose(true);}}></div>
        </div>

    )

}
```

Class Tasks:

```
class Tasks extends React.Component{  
    renderTask(task, id){
        return <Task
            task = {task}
            id = {id}
            onRemoveClick = {() => this.props.onRemoveClick(id)}
       />
     }

     render(){
         const tasks = this.props.tasks.map((step, move) => {
             console.log("[TASKS] ", step)
             return(
                 this.renderTask(step, move)
             )
         })

         return (
            <div className="tasks">{tasks}</div>
        )
    }
 }
```

Class ToDoLlist:

```
class ToDoList extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tasks : []
        }
    }
    removeTask(id){
        const tasks = this.state.tasks;
        tasks.splice(id, 1)
        this.setState({tasks : tasks})
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="ToDoList_box">
                <Tasks
                    tasks = {this.state.tasks}
                    onRemoveClick = {(id) => this.removeTask(id)}

                 />

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

the application is a rectangle, one large rectangle, in which other rectangles with tasks are added (at the same time they are added by slide animation, for this I use the .add_task css class)

to delete tasks, I placed a corresponding button next to each task, and in order for the tasks to disappear animatedly, similarly to the appearance, I came up with such logic, the user clicks on the delete button, the setClose hook is called (which is false by default) and updated to true, at the beginning the class contains a check, the close values, in accordance with which, the onRemoveClick prop is called, and the removal animation is assigned...

as a result of all this long history, I get absolutely not the result that I would like, the Tasks class passes the correct values, but the Task function displays completely different from what is passed to it (I think this is due to the fact that I prematurely update one of tasks, changing its state, maybe it somehow affects, but I don’t know there)...

I hope someone has the strength to read all this, and perhaps understand me ..

I also attached two screenshots from the browser above, where the first after adding 5 tasks, and the second after deleting the 3rd task:

[adding 5 tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcJnG.jpg)

[deleting the 3rd task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm2nl.jpg),

Comment: `const tasks = [...this.state.tasks]`